# How to add dynamic jquery mobile Back button?

Tags: android, jquery, cordova, jquery-mobile

Since jquery mobile back button doesn't work well in different pages i have tried to add dynamic back button .Here's what i did

```
$("#page1").bind("pagecreate",function() {
if(page2 == 1){
            $('<div data-role="button" id="back"><a data-icon="arrow-l" href="pag2.html">Back</a></div>').prependTo("div:jqmData(role='header')");
            $("back").button();
        }else{
            $('<div data-role="button" id="back"><a data-icon="arrow-l"   href="default.html">Back</a></div>').prependTo("div:jqmData(role='header')");
            $("back").button();
        }
}
```

when the button is prepend to the header its not having jquery mobile button styles it showsup like a plain link and moves all other header content down.Any help would be appericiated.

Answer (score 1):

You need to enhance new markup with:

trigger("create")

Take a look at [this](http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/pages/page-scripting.html) jQuery mobile documentation.

Comment: it should work but i have copied the whole css applied for the back itself while appending.Thanks for ur help.

Answer (score 0):

Format of adding button to particular id is not,

```
$("back").button();
```

It should be,

```
$("#back").button();
```

If you are using class,

```
$(".back").button();
```

Kindly update your code. Hope this helps for your case.